# How to prevent using too much if statements in this situation?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a python3x program that does something when user enter a special command. For example I have commands like this : !add, !edit, !remove 
and I have functions to do what I want ,like : add()  edit()  remove(). 
One way to do this is to write program using if statements but I have lot's of commands and I am looking for a better idea.
I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example on how you can call functions by using a string to identify the name of the function you want to call:

```
def hello():
    print("Hello")


def world():
    print("World")


helloFunc = globals()["hello"]
helloFunc()

worldFunc = locals()["world"]
worldFunc()
```

The output will look like this:

```
Hello
World
```

In essence, you can substitute the string literal for a variable, which would be part of the command that the user entered